# C++ Writing/reading from/to a socket using Winsock

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, proxy, winsock

I have Visual Studio Express on Windows 7 and I'm trying to create a TCP Proxy Server in C++. I've got a server right now that works, but, using the proxy setting in Internet Explorer, it will only send and receive bytes. I can't make it write data to my screen.

I know this can be accomplished with read() write() in C, but I don't think that works out for C++ on Windows. Is there an alternative?

Also, can anyone give me a guideline on how to implement the proxy server? I'd really appreciate any information, tutorials, suggestions, or anything helpful at all. I'm pretty new to socket programming, and there doesn't seem to be much at all about C++ proxy servers on the net.

Basically tring to convert this into a proxy server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737593(v=VS.85).aspx

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Writing a proxy server and writing a server that listens on a socket are two different things. The link you give above is for the latter, not the former. I would recommend learning boost::asio (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) rather than mucking about with WinSock.

Answer (score 2):

A proxy server is just a listening server that accepts an inbound client connection, makes an outbound client connection to another server, and then passes data back and forth between the two connections. You have already seen MSDN's server example, now study its [client example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737591.aspx). Once you understand that, then study [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), which explains how HTTP works, and study [Web Proxy Tunneling](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt), which explains how the HTTP `CONNECT` command works.  Internet Explorer uses `CONNECT` when talking to a proxy.

Comment: depends on the type of proxy, http proxy yes, socks no.. it uses socks protocol.

Comment: A SOCKS proxy is a bit easier to implement than an HTTP proxy.  See SOCKS v4 (http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/socks/socks4/SOCKS4.protocol) and RFC 1928 for SOCKS v5(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).

Comment: I've written socks clients in C / C++ before, well aware of the RFC's for them, but TY for posting them again:)